# HTML - Table - Edit Row, option selected by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L94grLm0/)

Trying to get ether tb_edit_row(x) or tb_edit2_row(x) to work correctly.

When executing both function's. I get the same result for Access as: `<option value="0">Select One...</option>` but I should be getting result: `<option value="2">Admin</option>`

HTML:

```
    <form action="#">
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td><button disabled>Add</button></td>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Access</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="tb_edit_1" onclick="tb_edit_row(1)">Edit</button></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="tb_edit_2" onclick="tb_edit2_row(2)">Edit</button></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Java Script:

tb_edit_row(x)

```
function tb_edit_row(x) {
    var tb_Name, tb_Length, check, ID, Access, edit, submit;

    tb_Name = document.getElementById('myTable');
    tb_Length = tb_Name.rows.length;
    for (var i = 1; i <= tb_Length; i += 1) {
        check = tb_Name.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
        if (check == x) {
            ID = tb_Name.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            Access = tb_Name.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            tb_Name.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
            tb_Name.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" disabled value="'+ID+'">';
            tb_Name.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<select id="access_'+ID+'"><option value="0">Select One...</option><option value="1">User</option><option value="2">Admin</option></select>';
            document.getElementById('access_'+ID).selected = Access;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

tb_edit2_row(x)

```
function tb_edit2_row(x) {
    var tb_Name, tb_Length, check, ID, Access, edit, submit;

    tb_Name = document.getElementById('myTable');
    tb_Length = tb_Name.rows.length;
    for (var i = 1; i <= tb_Length; i += 1) {
        check = tb_Name.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
        if (check == x) {
            ID = tb_Name.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
            Access = tb_Name.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            tb_Name.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
            tb_Name.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = '<input type="text" disabled value="'+ID+'">';
            switch (Access) {
                case (1):
                    tb_Name.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<select id="access_'+ID+'"><option value="">Select One...</option><option value="1" selected>User</option><option value="2">Admin</option></select>';
                case (2):
                    tb_Name.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<select id="access_'+ID+'"><option value="">Select One...</option><option value="1">User</option><option value="2" selected>Admin</option></select>';
                default:
                    tb_Name.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<select id="access_'+ID+'"><option value="" selected>Select One...</option><option value="1">User</option><option value="2">Admin</option></select>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing the `document.getElementById('access_'+ID).value` instead of `.selected` (in tb_edit_row) -> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp. Same in `<select id="access_'+ID+' " value="1">`.

Comment: I tried out the fiddle you edited in and noticed several other issues in tb_edit_row2 -> `Access` is string but in switch statement you are comparing to int. It does not work in fiddle. However if you do `case "2"` you jump into the correct branch. But even if you jump into the correct branch you do not have a brake/return statement in it. Because it is missing, even if you jump to case 1, case 2 and default will execute too. Same goes for the branch 2, default will still execute (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Comment: Thank you, I will be using tb_edit_row(x) now that its working correct.